# textarea cannot be adjust bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I couldnt adjust the size of my textarea. it appear to be very big. I tried include rows="4" but it doesnt seems to become smaller. can someone help?I couldnt adjust the size of my textarea. it appear to be very big. I tried include rows="4" but it doesnt seems to become smaller. can someone help?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class= "main col-sm-9">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" data-toggle="validator" action="updatediary.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="date" class="col-md-2 control-label">Date:</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $date; ?>"readonly />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subject" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Status:</label>
            <div class="col-md-5" >
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $status; ?>"readonly />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subject" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" value="<?php echo $subject; ?>"readonly>


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="detail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Detail:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="detail" rows="2"  readonly><?php echo $detail; ?></textarea>
            </div>
            </div>


    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar col-xs-3 pull-right">
     <div class="well">sidebar</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a size to it as big as u want with css. I wrote inline css but you can move it to a class.

```html
<textarea class="form-control" name="detail" rows="2"  readonly style="height:10px; !important;"><?php echo $detail; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: can you please add a screenshot to see how it looks? maybe a class is overriding it.

Comment: I have remove all my coding and only left with this but the textarea still not reducing its size

Comment: I've changed the code. This should definitely work. Probably something is just overriding your code with !important property.